# Interpretation of the vector current in field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

In field theory we write

$$J^\mu=\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\mu\Psi$$

But I can't understand why it is so. Could anyone explain each of the terms in the multiplication?

Comment: Do you mean $\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}\Psi$?

Comment: @user110373 Well, I am not so sure. I got the notation above from Thomson, Modern Particle Physics. I don't know why he uses $\phi$.

Comment: It is called vector current because $J^{\mu}$ transform as a vector under Lorentz group.

Comment: Up to a constant, this is just the electromagnetic 4-current. For example, the zero component is $\Psi^\dagger \Psi$ which is the electron density, proportional to the charge density.

Answer (score 1):

Well, such form follows from the Noether theorem, which states that if action (in Minkowski space-time)
$$
S = \int d^{4}xL
$$ 
of fermions $\Psi$ is invariant under transformation
$$
\tag 1 \Psi \to e^{i\alpha}\Psi , \quad \bar{\Psi} \to e^{-i\alpha}\bar{\Psi},
$$
then exists the object $J$ with one vector indice, namely
$$
\tag 2 J_{\mu} = i\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial^{\mu}\Psi)}\alpha \Psi - i\alpha \bar{\Psi}\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial^{\mu}\bar{\Psi})},
$$
which is conserved:
$$
\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu} = 0
$$
Conservation law can be rewritten in the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega} d^{3}\mathbf r J^{0} \equiv \frac{dQ}{dt} = -\int_{d\Omega} d\mathbf {S}\cdot \mathbf J, 
$$
which means that the changing with time the quantity $\int J^{0}d^{3}\mathbf r$ in the given volume $\Omega$ is related to the flux of quantity $\mathbf J$ through surface $d\Omega$.

The scalar quantity $Q$ is thus called charge (with $J^{0}$ being charge density), while the quantity $\mathbf J$ is current density.

The vector nature of $J^{\mu}$ follows from the fact that the transformation $(1)$ isn't related to space-time transfrormations, while indices are. So the only quantity which can be $J$ in our case is the vector (one indice comes from expilcit expression for Noether current).

As for explicit form of current $J^{\mu}$, let's use particular lagrangian of free fermions, 
$$
L = \bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\Psi ,
$$
with $\gamma_{\mu}$ being Dirac matrices, $\Psi$ being Dirac spinor, $\bar{\Psi} \equiv \Psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$ being Dirac conjugated spinor. Such lagrangian is constructed from the requirement of Lorentz invariance and from requirement that we obtain Dirac equation for field with spin $\frac{1}{2}$ after using Euler-Lagrange equations.

and insert it into $(2)$. You'll immediately obtain the result (up to the sign, which isn't relevant here).